# How can I use sails.js model with associations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I want to create a node.js application using sails.js with the following DB design:

`Products <----> ProductAttributes <----> Attributes`

*Please note that this is a given design and cannot be changed.*

Althought sails.js does not support model associations yet, I want to know if it's possible for me to override the Model's CRUD methods or even create my own, in order to apply the above design to sails.js.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get involved in the development of associations, send a note to the Google Group.  In the mean time, what we do is, for SQL-based databases, use `Model.query()`, and for nosql databases, use two separate calls when you need to access the data.

Hope that helps, and look out for updates from us on this as the summer progresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the associations in the Sails.js v0.10. npm install sails@git://github.com/balderdashy/sails.git#v0.10

and here is the documentation.. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelAssociations.md